# VBA Excel to Word - For next loops skips data randomly

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have been struggling with a piece of code and I cannot seem to find the correct solution.

**What the code should do:**

I want to copy multiple rows in Excel, based on an 'if' statement saying:
"If column C is 1, then copy cells Ax:Dx from the Excel sheet and paste that data into a word file"

The word file is generated normally in the code before this part. This works without any issue.

Example:
[image]

**What is the code:**

(Blad = sheet)

```
 k = Blad2.Range("A1", Blad2.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
 Worksheets("Prijzen").Activate
    For i = 1 To k
        rij = worksheets("Prijzen").Range("C2").Offset(i - 1).Value
        If rij >= 1 Then
           Blad2.Range("A2:D2").Offset(i - 1).Copy
           .PasteExcelTable False, True, False

        End If
    Next
```

**What the code actually does**

Example result

[image: Example result]

Example result 2

[image: ex3]

There were "1"'s in 6 rows, so normally the code should generate 6 codes.
So, one way or another, the code just skips lines or places 2 times the same line. 
When I debug using F8, everthing is placed correct.

**What I tried**

Adding delays, Reading through the internet,changing the table formats, but unfortunately unsuccessful.

**---EDIT---**
I implemented the advice of Scott and tried debugging with each line. If I debug in the loop, everything is pasted 100% correctly. When I remove the line so all goes automatic, it starts skipping lines again or making double lines.

I let it run 3 times in a row and i got the following
[image: Example multiple outcomes]

I tried adding a DoEvents loop around the copy statement, but this still gives the same result.

```
        Dim tmpstart
    For i = 1 To k

        Ccol = ws2.Range("C2").Offset(i - 1).Value
           If Ccol >= 1 Then

            tmpstart = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                ws2.Range("A2:D2").Offset(i - 1).Copy
            Loop While (tmpstart + 1) > Timer

            .PasteExcelTable False, True, False

           End If
    Next
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Many thanks,

Filip

Comment: Nicely asked question :)  Suggest adding `debug.print "loop: " & i & " rij = " & rij` just above your if statement see if the loop is skipping iterations.

Comment: Did you have any luck with `debug.print` ?

Comment: Hi ShowLearner, thank you for your advice. I have tried the debug.print and also a msgbox. Doing this, the loops are running fine. It must be a fault with the connection between copying in Excel and Pasting in word. That the system does not get enough time to 1) copy, 2) paste or 3) placing the mouse indicator. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So... not skipping loops with the debug print??

Comment: Entered too fast :-). No, no skipping of loops if I debug print the program. I also tried running the program without making word active & visible, but the results are the same unfortunately. Looks like to computer just needs to slow down and take its time to finish the loops.

Comment: Try running Orlandos VBA decompiler / decompacter... sorry you'll have to google it... make a backup

Comment: Oké, I will try! Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Any luck with the decompiler?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing two different worksheets.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Prijzen") 'or Blad2 which ever is correct.
k = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For i = 1 To k
    rij = ws.Range("C2").Offset(i - 1).Value
    If rij >= 1 Then
        ws.Range("A2:D2").Offset(i - 1).Copy
        .PasteExcelTable False, True, False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your advice. 
The 2 worksheets that I referred to were actually the same. I have changed it to your correction, but, unfortunately, I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

After confirming that your code runs with a `Debug.Print` statement in the `For ... Next` loop I think we can safely say that there is nothing wrong with the code.  I'm going out on a limb and suggesting you try this tool: http://cpap.com.br/orlando/VBADecompilerMore.asp

I've had similar experiences and enjoyed a lot of success by using the VBA Decompiler.

A few notes, AV software does NOT seem to like this download, Orlando is a MS MVP but the tool does tricky stuff. You may (probably will) need to disable your AV to download it.

---

Of course... there are other ways to test if this might make a difference...

Create a new, FRESH, document and retype (or copy via a plain text editor) the code - this lets you test in a document that should have no corruptions...

HTH

Comment: Thanks once again. The decompiler is not available anymore on the website. I searched for another download link without succes. I noticed something else: If I do the debug.print and run the program (not debugging in steps), the fault is still there. I also created a fresh document and retyped the cycle, but the same this occurs. I think there is a malprocedure in copying and pasting the information to and from the clipboard. I tried something like this: Sheet1.Range("A1:A200").Copy Destination:=wordapp.selection but this code is not totally correct. 
This all is really frustrating :-)

Comment: I am going to try something else.
With userforms I am going to try to make the exact table I need. Afterwards, copying the page in 1 time from Excel to Word. Fingers crossed !

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to get it fixed, it seems that copying to clipboard from Excel, and pasting from clipboard in Word, given too uncertain and random results to work with. Lines are getting posted double and some lines won't show up.

**My workaround:**

```
i = 1
    Ccol = 1
    ws2.Activate

    'count rows in sheet, copy & paste title on a location "Budget" in Word.
    k = ws2.Range("A1", Blad3.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        .Goto what:=-1, Name:="Budget"
        ws2.Range("A1:D1").Offset(i - 1).Copy
        .BoldRun
        .PasteExcelTable False, True, False
        .BoldRun

    For i = 1 To k
        If ws2.Range("C2").Offset(i - 1) >= 1 Then

            'Copy - Paste to different Excel sheet without using the clipboard
            ws2.Range("A2:D2").Offset(i - 1).Copy Destination:=ws6.Range("A1:D1").Offset(Ccol - 1)
            'Ccol is used to paste the copied data on rows 1, 2, ...
            Ccol = Ccol + 1

        End If
    Next
    ' making sure columns/rows width/heigth is ok
    ws6.Activate
    ws6.Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    ws6.Rows(1).AutoFit

    'counting the amount of lines in the sheet and copying the complete table
    k2 = ws6.Range("A1", ws6.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    ws6.Range("A1", Range("D1").Offset(k2 - 1)).Copy

    'Program pauze before pasting
        tmpStart = Timer
        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop While (tmpStart + 1) > Timer
    .PasteExcelTable False, True, False
```

So basically, I just coppied each line with a "1" in the C-column and pasted the cells in the same Excel file. When everything is pasted to 1 sheet (this seems to work quite good), I copy everything and paste it into the Word file.

Although the original solution seems far more logical to me, I can finally move on with the work.